# MSVC Autoexp.dat tokens explanation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2010, there is a little bit of explanation at the beginning of autoexp.dat on how to define rules. However, this explanation is quite limited and I haven't come across any other document. Appreciate your help in understanding a few tokens.

Here is a rule I copied from somewhere. It works for my needs.

```
MyString{
    preview         ([$e.data,su])
    stringview      ([$e.data,sub])
}
```

Q1. What is the difference between preview and stringview? Do I really need stringview.

Q2. Why does stringview use "sub" and not "su?"

Q3. What does a hash (#) do on an expression? What is the difference between the following two lines?

```
   preview         ([$e.data,su])
   preview         #([$e.data,su])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. preview is that you see in Debuger's watch window, if you define stringview it will add a small icon (looking glass) witch calls a Text Visuzlisers. (read [StringView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_StringView))
2. [Format Specifiers in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. I think this is some syntax requirements like tokens #tree #list etc